# How to stream json.gz objects on S3 to Kinesis Firehose

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We have an application dropping json.gz files on to S3 bucket. I am looking for a solution that can consume these json.gz files and push on to Kinesis Firehose so that we can send the data on to downstream products.
I am aware of doing through a lambda function but looking for other integration solutions. Thanks.

Solution to stream JSON data on S3 to Amazon Kinesis Firehose with out use of lambda function.